# Build a Maven project and submit as the Flink job using Docker

Tags: java, docker, maven, docker-compose, apache-flink

I am trying to build a maven project using docker and submit a generated jar in flink. But in the end, some exception is occurring. Anyone can please help me to resolve the exception.

### Dockerfile

```
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim AS builder

COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app

RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM flink:1.10.0-scala_2.12
COPY --from=builder /home/app/target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/local/lib/demo.jar

ENV FLINK_HOME=/opt/flink
ENV PATH=$FLINK_HOME/bin:$PATH

WORKDIR $FLINK_HOME

EXPOSE 8081

ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/flink", "run", "-c", "com.demo.app.App", "/usr/local/lib/demo.jar"]
```

### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  demo:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: demoapp
    expose:
      - "6121"
      - "6122"
      - "6123"
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"
```

### Exception

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Building demo
Step 1/10 : FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8-slim AS builder
 ---> addee4586ff4
Step 2/10 : COPY src /home/app/src
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 24e9837c9bc5
Step 3/10 : COPY pom.xml /home/app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 13965367c201
Step 4/10 : RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0a6dec38b357
Step 5/10 : FROM flink:1.10.0-scala_2.12
 ---> d373f7bf2f75
Step 6/10 : COPY --from=builder /home/app/target/demo-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar /usr/local/lib/demo.jar
 ---> 431c3080d639
Step 7/10 : ENV FLINK_HOME=/opt/flink
 ---> Running in bbae40bc5d84
Removing intermediate container bbae40bc5d84
 ---> 59171a4fd11e
Step 8/10 : ENV PATH=$FLINK_HOME/bin:$PATH
 ---> Running in 45e30a54e742
Removing intermediate container 45e30a54e742
 ---> 4e986527391a
Step 9/10 : WORKDIR $FLINK_HOME
 ---> Running in 1f0ca2067595
Removing intermediate container 1f0ca2067595
 ---> aa817f1dee2d
Step 10/10 : ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/flink", "run", "-c", "com.demo.app.App", "/usr/local/lib/demo.jar"]
 ---> Running in f984981dfbc8
Removing intermediate container f984981dfbc8
 ---> 1cdc22379a90
Successfully built 1cdc22379a90
Successfully tagged demo:latest
Creating demo ... 
Creating demo ... done
Attaching to demo
demo | 
demo | ------------------------------------------------------------
demo |  The program finished with the following exception:
demo | 
demo | org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:335)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:205)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:138)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:664)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:213)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:895)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:968)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:968)
demo | Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
demo |  at org.apache.flink.util.ExceptionUtils.rethrow(ExceptionUtils.java:199)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1741)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamContextEnvironment.java:94)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:63)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1620)
demo |  at com.demo.app.App.main(App.java:105)
demo |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
demo |  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
demo |  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
demo |  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:321)
demo |  ... 8 more
demo | Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:357)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1908)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:1736)
demo |  ... 17 more
demo | Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionException: Failed to submit JobGraph.
demo |  at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$submitJob$7(RestClusterClient.java:359)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:884)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniExceptionally.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:866)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$8(FutureUtils.java:287)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:774)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:750)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:488)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:1990)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.runtime.rest.RestClient.lambda$submitRequest$1(RestClient.java:342)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:500)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:493)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:472)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:413)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:538)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:531)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:111)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:323)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:339)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:685)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
demo |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
demo | Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils$RetryException: Could not complete the operation. Number of retries has been exhausted.
demo |  at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$8(FutureUtils.java:284)
demo |  ... 21 more
demo | Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:292)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:308)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniCompose(CompletableFuture.java:957)
demo |  at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:940)
demo |  ... 19 more
demo | Caused by: org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: localhost/127.0.0.1:8081
demo | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
demo |  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
demo |  at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:714)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:336)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:685)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
demo |  at org.apache.flink.shaded.netty4.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
demo |  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Also, checked the running containers, but not running any container.

### Build Command that I used

```
sudo docker-compose up --build
```

### Also tried to build using this command

```
docker run --rm -it demo:latest
sudo docker build -t demo .
```

But the result same exception

Answer (score 3):

This isn't how to go about running Flink with docker. You need to arrange for a Job Manager and at least one Task Manager to be started -- you can't use `./bin/flink run` without first creating a cluster for the job to run on.

A good way to learn your way around this topic is to work through the [Flink Operations Playground](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/try-flink/flink-operations-playground.html), which includes a complete docker-based infrastructure you can use as a starting point for your own projects.

There's also [documentation on how to run Flink on Docker](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/deployment/docker.html).

Comment: Thanks!. You are right I just forget about the run Flink job manager and task manager service now I have fix the issue Its working fine now.

Comment: I want to ask one question is that necessary to always build source files to generate .jar file on the production server using maven or we can simply generate jar file locally and push to the production server.

Comment: You can use docker to bring up a session cluster, and then push client jars to that remote cluster. Or you can build a per-job image that includes the job jar. Building the jar on the production server is not typical.